# immutable value is still being moved

Tags: rust, closures, borrow-checker, ownership, borrowing

I can't get this function to compile:

```rust
/// Return a String with all characters masked as '#' except the last 4.
fn maskify(cc: &str) -> String {
    let chars = cc.to_string().chars();
    chars
        .enumerate()
        .map(|(i, c)| {
            if i > chars.count() - 4 { '#' } else { c }
        })
        .collect()    
}
```

The current errors are:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `chars`, a captured variable in an `FnMut` closure
 --> src/lib.rs:7:21
  |
3 |     let chars = cc.to_string().chars();
  |         ----- captured outer variable
...
7 |             if i > &chars.count() - 4 { '#' } else { c }
  |                     ^^^^^ move occurs because `chars` has type `std::str::Chars<'_>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
 --> src/lib.rs:3:17
  |
3 |     let chars = cc.to_string().chars();
  |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
  |                 |
  |                 creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
4 |     chars
  |     ----- borrow later used here
  |
  = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value

error[E0382]: use of moved value: `chars`
 --> src/lib.rs:6:14
  |
3 |     let chars = cc.to_string().chars();
  |         ----- move occurs because `chars` has type `std::str::Chars<'_>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
4 |     chars
  |     ----- value moved here
5 |         .enumerate()
6 |         .map(|(i, c)| {
  |              ^^^^^^^^ value used here after move
7 |             if i > &chars.count() - 4 { '#' } else { c }
  |                     ----- use occurs due to use in closure
```

I think the source of the error is that `chars` is an iterator, so it mutates, making it impossible to borrow in the closure, but even if I try to declare a local variable (such as `let count = chars.count()`), I still get borrow errors.

I've tried dereferencing it with `&`, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The crux of the issue here is that `Char::count()` consumes `self`. Even if you declare a local variable, you cannot use `chars` after you moved ownership to the `count` function:

```rust
fn maskify(cc: &str) {
  let chars = cc.to_string().chars();
   // ^^^^^ move occurs here
  let count = chars.count();
                 // ^^^^^^ `chars` moved because `count` consumes self
  let _ = chars.enumerate();
       // ^^^^^ value used here after move - *this is not allowed*
}
```

You can fix this issue by creating a new iterator and consuming that to get the `count`:

```rust
fn maskify(cc: &str) -> String {
    let chars = cc.chars();
    let count = cc.chars().count();
             // ^^^ create and consume a new iterator over cc
    chars
        .enumerate()
        .map(|(i, c)| {
            if i < count - 4 { '#' } else { c }
        })
        .collect()    
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(maskify("abcd1234"), "####1234");
}
```

Or you can get the length of the string with `.len()`:

```rust
fn maskify(cc: &str) -> String {
    let chars = cc.chars();
    chars
        .enumerate()
        .map(|(i, c)| {
            if i < cc.len() - 4 { '#' } else { c }
        })
        .collect()    
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(maskify("abcd1234"), "####1234");
}
```

Note that `str.len()` can *only* handle ascii while `.chars().count()` can handle full utf8.

Comment: I would use `cc.chars().count()`, not `cc.len()`, to better support Unicode. (That still doesn't handle everything but it's closer.)

Comment: Great explanation - and yes - I also noticed that `len` isn't right here, but adding another `count()` makes this work.

Comment: @mzedeler Why isn't `len` right? The assertion passes.

Comment: @IbraheemAhmed `.len()` is the number of bytes (UTF8 code units), `chars` works in terms of codepoints. UTF8 has 1-4 bytes per codepoint, so the code will misbehave for anything outside of ascii (e.g. non-latin script, diacritics, emoji, ...). For instance if you maskify "école" using `cc.len()`, you will only get 3 unmasked characters, and things get worse as you get further away from ascii, "देवनागरी" will have *no characters unmasked* with a bytes-based count, because it has 8 codepoints but encodes as 24 bytes.

Comment: Although note that even the codepoint version will break due to multi-codepoint characters e.g. "देवनागरी" above has 8 codepoints but 5 "characters" (grapheme clusters), so maskifying it yields a broken result even using a codepoints count: "####ागरी" only has 2.5 "characters" of the original (the final two "characters", and a combining codepoint tacked onto a `#`).

Comment: So your final line should really be that `str.len()` *only* handles ascii, it's completely broken otherwise (and one could argue that it's plain broken any time you're trying to manipulate characters). If using `str::len`, the function should probably fail on getting a non-ascii codepoint, whether panicing entirely or just resulting in an `Err`.

Comment: One more question - when you write that `count()` consumes `self`, I assume that it iterates to the end in order to count the number of chars? I must admit it blows my mind if the compiler is able to infer that at compile time.

Comment: Yet another side question: if the iterator is used backwards, I guess we can save one scan across the length, because we would then just output the first four chars and output `#` for anything left.

Comment: @mzedeler the compiler knows that `count` consumes `self` because `count` takes `self` as a parameter (meaning it takes ownership) as opposed to taking `&self` (borrowing). It is not really inferring anything there, it's all in the function signature.

Answer (score 3):

Two slightly different approaches you can use to implement this function depending on whether or not `cc` is UTF8 or ASCII. The UTF8 implementation of course works for both cases as UTF8 is a superset of ASCII.

```rust
fn maskify_utf8(cc: &str) -> String {
    let last_four = cc.chars().count().saturating_sub(4);
    cc.chars()
        .enumerate()
        .map(|(i, c)| if i < last_four { '#' } else { c })
        .collect()    
}

fn maskify_ascii(cc: &str) -> String {
    let mask_idx = cc.len().saturating_sub(4);
    format!("{0:#<1$}{2}", "#", mask_idx, &cc[mask_idx..])
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(maskify_utf8("1234"), "####1234");
    assert_eq!(maskify_utf8("abcd1234"), "####1234");
    assert_eq!(maskify_ascii("abcd1234"), "####1234");
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c485eeec70e4252c5db1bb42d50dd607)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ibraheem-ahmed, I wound up with this solution:

```
/// Return a String with all characters masked as '#' except the last 4.
fn maskify(cc: &str) -> String {
    let leading = cc.chars().count().saturating_sub(4);
    cc
        .chars()
        .enumerate()
        .map(|(i, c)| {
            if i >= leading { c } else { '#' }
        })
        .collect()    
}
```